# Is it possible to change the didExitRegion Time using android-beacon-library

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon

I am working with iBeacons and using the AltBeacon library.

I would ask if it is possible to change the time between the last beacon was seen and didExitRegion is called.

I found the public static long INSIDE_EXPIRATION_MILLIS = 100001, so I assume the time is 10 seconds. Is this right?

Unfortunately I didn´t found any way to set another value.

Is there any other method that shows me when no beacon is seen for a specific time? (3-5 seconds)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/)'s  region exit is triggered 10 seconds after a beacon is last seen, and the java constant you reference is the only way this can be configured.  Changing this means recompiling source for the library.

Making this configurable at run time is as reasonable new feature request.  If you are interested in creating one, please do so here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/new

Also, if you have the skills, we'd welcome you making the change yourself and submitting a pull request on GitHub.  This is how the best open source software gets built!

Until this feature is added, you can make the exit time longer by adding a timer in the didExitRegion callback.  Making it shorter is trickier, but you could use a timer on a didRangeBeaconsInRegion callback, and cancel the timer if you get another callback before it goes off.

One caution on making the time shorter: not all beacon packets get received by mobile devices, and some beacons do not transmit very frequently.  The default exit time on iOS is only 3 seconds, and this often leads to intermittent exit/entry events when slowly advertising beacons (those that transmit at only 1 Hz) are around a phone that misses three transmissions in a row.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now i did an exitCounter in the didRangeBeaconsInRegion callback. It´s not so exact but it works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

For new readers:

```
BeaconManager.setRegionExitPeriod(2000); // 2 seconds
```